# IF, Join and concat not working in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have two tables, one of which contains 3000 area codes (so just the first half of the postcode) and the other table containing shops details with a column called `postcodes_covered` which are all the area codes that a particular shop covers for example: 
shop 1 (AB1,AB2,AB3,AB4,AB5...), shop 2 (E15,E13,E14 ...) etc. I need to create a report which contains the 3000 area codes and a column that says "Yes" if an area code from table 2 is contained in table 1 or "No" if that area code is not covered. I have written an SQL query which works fine however, i need to write it in codeigniter. The code i have written for codeigniter doesn't seem to work and i don't know why?

**SQL query:**

```
select bodyshops_postcode_allocation.area_code,if(postcodes_covered is null,"No","Yes") as "YeN" from bodyshops_postcode_allocation left join bodyshops on bodyshops.postcodes_covered like concat("%",bodyshops_postcode_allocation.area_code,"%");
```

**Codeigniter:**

```
    function postcode_allocation()
{
    $this->db->select('bodyshops_postcode_allocation.area_code as area_code')
            ->select('IF(bodyshops.postcodes_covered is null, "No", "Yes") as match_found')
            ->join('bodyshops', 'bodyshops.postcodes_covered LIKE CONCAT("%",bodyshops_postcode_allocation.area_code,"%")')
            ->from('bodyshops_postcode_allocation');


    $this->load->dbutil();
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($this->db->get(''));

    $this->output->set_header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    $this->output->set_header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=postcode_allocation.csv; size=".strlen($data));
    $this->output->set_output($data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using SQL function like this in CodeIgniter, you need to tell it not to try to escape the query.

```
->select('IF(bodyshops.postcodes_covered is null, "No", "Yes") as match_found', FALSE)
```

The `FALSE` tells CodeIgniter to leave the string as-as and not try to add backticks to it.  It doesn't know how to add them in this case, so it messes up your query.

P.S. your join needs to be:

```
->join('bodyshops', 'bodyshops.postcodes_covered LIKE CONCAT("%",bodyshops_postcode_allocation.area_code,"%")', 'left')
```

If you want a LEFT JOIN, you need to tell it so.

P.P.S. `$this->db->get('')` should really just be `$this->db->get()`.  Don't pass it a blank string.

Comment: i have made some modifications like you have said however, i am still getting an error. Have i used the like and concat operators correctly? @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @user3009232: Looks fine to me.  What error are you getting?  What do you see if you do `echo $this->db->last_query();` (after the `$this->db->get()` call).

Comment: i am getting error: 1064 "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`LIKE` CONCAT("%",bodyshops_postcode_allocation.area_code,"%")' at line 3"... and when i put the echo $this->db->last_query(); i get the same error. @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @user3009232: Putting `echo $this->db->last_query();` doesn't give you an error.  The program is dying at that error, so no other code is running.  I think I know what's going on...

Comment: i have no idea? :S @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @user3009232: As a last resort you can do: `$query = $this->db->query('select bodyshops_postcode_allocation.area_code ...');`  And then `$data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);`

Comment: i tried your solution however i still got an error. What i tried instead was paste my original SQL query into codeigniter instead of the other code i wrote and it seemed to have worked fine. Thanks though! @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @user3009232: So, you got it working?  If so, glad I could help.